# Wave file will not play with Teensy 3.5

Tags: sd-card, audio, teensy

I am attempting to play a wav file from an SD card using a Teensy 3.5. I am using [this buzzer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B085XQM69Z) and I have the following code currently:

```
#include <Audio.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <SerialFlash.h>

// GUItool: begin automatically generated code
AudioPlaySdWav           playSdWav1;     //xy=557,157
AudioOutputPWM           pwm1;           //xy=889,184
AudioConnection          patchCord1(playSdWav1, 0, pwm1, 0);
AudioConnection          patchCord2(playSdWav1, 1, pwm1, 0);
// GUItool: end automatically generated code

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(4800);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println("Play");
  playSdWav1.play("sound.wav");
  delay(100);
  while (playSdWav1.isPlaying()) {
    delay (100);
  }
}
```

I don't know which pin is supposed to be outputting the PWM signal. I tried searching "patchCord1" to see what the parameters for it are, but was unsuccessful. The code was generated by [The Audio System Design Tool.](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/gui/index.html)

As for the hardware configuration, I am attempting to wire the `I/O` pin to various PWM pins (to check for output) with no success. I have `GND` to Analog Ground and `VCC` to 3.3V (250 mA max). This is according to [this diagram](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/970x728/3267-04.jpg).

Which PIN is the Teensy supposed to output the pulses to?

Edit:

I can get the buzzer to work by using manual PWM (analogWrite), so I know that it functions.

Comment: I will edit the question to add a little bit of specifics. But, my question is first, which pin is supposed to be connected to `I/O`. And second, am I doing this right at all?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation implies you have to combine pins 3 and 4.

Here is a circuit diagram:

https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/gui/img/pwmdualcircuit.jpg

[image]

Source:

https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/gui/?info=AudioOutputPWM

Comment: After wiring it this way, I still receive no sound. But, I am noticing that the serial monitor is constantly entering "Play." But, it seems it shouldn't do that until the sound has completed? The sound is 5 seconds and it's doing about 10 per second.